# React multiple imports of same file

Tags: reactjs, import

I know the doubt is very basic but I haven't found an answer yet.

Here it goes:

Let's say I have a `utils` file that exports some function and I'm using that same `utils` function in many of my React components.

This is what I'm currently doing:

**component1:**

    `import { parseData } from '@/utils/parser';`

**component2:**

    `import { parseData } from '@/utils/parser';`

How can I avoid importing it on every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **webpack** there is a plugin called [PluginProvider](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):

And maybe you can use it like this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  parseData: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '@/utils/parser'),
});
```